# IOS (Swift) loading images from Flickr

Tags: ios, json, swift

Hi I am trying to load images from Flickr and display them in tableview, which I do using following 3 methods:

```
func createConnection(){
    let url = NSURL(string: "https://api.flickr.com/services/rest/?method=flickr.photos.getRecent&api_key=" + apiKey + "&per_page=20&format=json&nojsoncallback=1")!
    let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
    let task = session.dataTaskWithURL(url, completionHandler: {data, response, error in self.loadImages(data!)})
    task.resume()
}

func loadImages(data: NSData?) {
    guard data != nil else{
        print("Error")
        return
    }
    do {
        let jsonData = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: .AllowFragments)
        let photos = jsonData["photos"] as! NSDictionary
        let photoList = photos["photo"] as! NSArray
        for imageData in  photoList{
            let theTitle = imageData["title"] as! String
            let farm = imageData["farm"]!
            let server = imageData["server"]!
            let secret = imageData["secret"]!
            let id = imageData["id"]!
            let imageURL = "https://farm\(farm!).staticflickr.com/\(server!)/\(id!)_\(secret!).jpg"
            let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
            let task = session.dataTaskWithURL(NSURL(string: imageURL)!, completionHandler: {
                data, response, error in self.addNewItem(theTitle, data: data)
            })

            task.resume()
        }


    }
    catch {
        print ("Error while loading data")
    }
}

func addNewItem(title: String, data: NSData?){
    guard data != nil else{
        print ("Error")
        return
    }
    let image = UIImage(data: data!)
    let item = Item(title: title, image: image)
    itemList.append(item)
    print (item.title)

}
```

I call the first method in viewDidLoad(), and then later using tableView methods I try to fetch images and image titles from the itemList[Item] array. For the testing purpose I use print (item.title) method in the addNewItem() method to see if the data is being obtained from the json file, and it prints all the image titles.
However, the problem is the table is still empty, hence I was wondering if it is because I did not use asynchronous download, although I don't know how to do that as I am new to IOS and Swift.
Please help

Comment: Are you refreshing your table view to let it know about new data. `reloadData()` is the method. Whenever there's a change in your data source, you call this method to let it refresh it self.

Comment: No I am not, where would I add the method? Sorry I am newbie in IOS

Comment: Probably at the end of your `addNewItem()`. I'm not sure if that's the structure you want, but I won't recommend holding a reference to a `UImage` in your `Item`. Instead just keep the URL and title in `Item` and load `UIImage` into `UIImageView` when needed.

Comment: Also, use some caching mechanism, there're some open source implementation of `UIImageView+Caching+Loading Server Image`, you might want to look at those to get the idea. [SDWebImage](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage), [AsyncImageView](https://github.com/nicklockwood/AsyncImageView)

Comment: I would highly recommend [Haneke](https://github.com/Haneke/Haneke) for image download and caching.